# Multiple responsive images over a single responsive image?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a map with multiple map pointers (7).

I have managed to get them in the correct positions using the following code.

```
  <div style="position:relative; left: 0; top: 0;">
              <img src="images/JCCareas.png"  class="img-responsive" style="position:relative; left: 0; top: 0;" alt="Map" />
              <img src="images/JCCtarget.png" class="img-responsive" style="position:absolute; left: 375px; top: 455px;" alt="target Solihull" title="Solihull"/>
              <img src="images/JCCtarget.png" class="img-responsive" style="position:absolute; left: 320px; top: 250px;" alt="target Sheldon"/>
              <img src="images/JCCtarget.png" class="img-responsive" style="position:absolute; left: 490px; top: 520px;" alt="target Knowle"/>
              <img src="images/JCCtarget.png" class="img-responsive" style="position:absolute; left: 290px; top: 365px;" alt="target Olton"/>
              <img src="images/JCCtarget.png" class="img-responsive" style="position:absolute; left: 575px; top: 390px;" alt="target Hampton-In-Arden"/>
              <img src="images/JCCtarget.png" class="img-responsive" style="position:absolute; left: 560px; top: 80px;" alt="target Coleshill"/>
              <img src="images/JCCtarget.png" class="img-responsive" style="position:absolute; left: 460px; top: 215px;" alt="target Marston Green"/>
   </div>
```

The map is being responsive but the map markers aren't i have tried a couple of ways in css but am really struggling to get this one working.

CSS i have tried:

```
#under-image {
position: relative;
display: inline;
}
#over-image {
position:absolute;
left:33%;
top:43%;
max-width: 10%;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please provide codepen or fiddle to get the idea.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yp7h2ezc/ this is just the base code

Comment: you can see the test environment at m3diapod.co.uk/jane

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this way `top` & `left` `position` in `%`

```
.img1{left: 28%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 49%;
}
.img2{left: 32%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 87%;
}
```

Comment: main image  apply css max-width:100%;

Comment: i have it working on jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/yp7h2ezc/1/ but it won't seem to work on the local version the targets aren't appearing any ideas?